# Vagrant Selenium-Grid: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: vagrant, protractor, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded [this vagrant selenium grid](https://github.com/abathingchris/selen) setup from GitHub, and tried it out as is. I can get my protractor tests working with the default firefox instances, but I am getting errors when trying to test on the chrome instances.  [Here is the log](http://uweb.txstate.edu/~wko4/code/bugLogs/chromedriverFail.log) output from the node vm's node.log file when I try to run a test with chrome.

I have tried using openjdk 6 & 7, and have tried the latest chromedriver (64Bit) as well as chromedriver 2.9 & 2.8, and tried the latest versions of the selenium-sever-standalone jar file.

I am using protractor 0.23.1 at the moment.  Here is my protractor config file:

```
exports.config = { 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
  chromeOnly: false,    
  splitTestsBetweenCapabilities: true,  
  specs: ['./e2e/**/*pec.js'], 

  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    'platform': 'LINUX',
    'maxInstances': 2, 
  }, {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'platform': 'ANY',
    'maxInstances': 2
  }], 

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

I have also tried adding the flags below to the script in the conf/upstart/selenium-node.conf file, but chrome still wont startup (same message as in log above).

```
 -browser "browserName=chrome" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/usr/bin/chromedriver"
```

Does anybody have this setup running with chrome? Or can you see what the problem is here?  Any advice could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try [opening an issue in that selen repository](https://github.com/abathingchris/selen/issues) since the provided vagrant doesn't seem to work out of the box.

Overall seems your goal here is to run selenium+chrome headless.

Take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294183/running-selenium-chromedriver-using-protractor-on-linux/25294834#25294834).