# Running protractor from Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, protractor

I am trying to run protractor on windows from the command line.
If I directly type the command:

```
webdriver-manager start
```

It works great.
However, from within jenkins, it keeps throwing:

```
'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My env vars seems ok, since the java and npm works fine from Jenkins.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turned out I simply forgot putting the C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm folder on the **System variables** and only configured it as my user path.

See elgalu's answer for your next problem though...

Answer (score 1):

Install Protractor globally in the Jenkins machine, for this you may need to ssh into the Jenkins machine that run the tests:

```
ssh your-jenkins-server
npm -g install protractor
# update webdriver in the Jenkins machine
webdriver-manager update
# test it works
webdriver-manager start
```

Once you have that setup and running your next problem will probably be [running Protractor headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294183/running-selenium-chromedriver-using-protractor-on-linux/25294834#25294834) unless your Jenkins machine has a display available and an installed windows manager like Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it still doesn't work without stating the complete path.. - C:\..\webdriver-manager start.
This is actually very wired since npm works fine from exactly the same path. I guess I might be missing something...
About the second part - running Protractor headless - it exactly my next place, Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i didn't see this was a Windows issue, you'll probably be better off by [running Selenium on your own](http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/#grid2) however, last time i run this on Windows i wrote a [blog post about it and worked ok for me](http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/#nodejs-win) i.e. didn't have to specify the full path.